# Camera java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera, runtimeexception

I have created a custom camera app using [this](https://github.com/davidgatti/dgCam) source code, but on few devices (like on High Resolution Devices) I am getting:

```
RuntimeException setParameters failed
```

I am facing this exception, due to this:

```
params.setPictureSize(1200, 900);
```

And I have noticed, If I use `(1600, 1200)` instead of `(1200, 900)` then I am not facing such issues

**Logcat:**

```
11-07 11:45:20.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3827): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-07 11:45:20.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3827): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {pl.gatti.dgcam/pl.gatti.dgcam.DgCamActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed
11-07 11:45:20.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3827):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2825)
11-07 11:45:20.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3827):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2854)
11-07 11:45:20.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3827):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2318)
11-07 11:45:20.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3827):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:144)
11-07 11:45:20.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3827):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
11-07 11:45:20.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3827):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-07 11:45:20.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3827):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152)
11-07 11:45:20.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3827):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5132)
11-07 11:45:20.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3827):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-07 11:45:20.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3827):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-07 11:45:20.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3827):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-07 11:45:20.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3827):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-07 11:45:20.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3827):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-07 11:45:20.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3827): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed
11-07 11:45:20.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3827):     at android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(Native Method)
11-07 11:45:20.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3827):     at android.hardware.Camera.setParameters(Camera.java:1490)
11-07 11:45:20.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3827):     at pl.gatti.dgcam.DgCamActivity.createCamera(DgCamActivity.java:124)
11-07 11:45:20.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3827):     at pl.gatti.dgcam.DgCamActivity.onResume(DgCamActivity.java:163)
11-07 11:45:20.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3827):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1185)
11-07 11:45:20.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3827):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5182)
11-07 11:45:20.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3827):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2815)
```

**Code:**

```
private void createCamera() {
        // Create an instance of Camera
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();

        // Setting the right parameters in the camera
        Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
        params.setPictureSize(1200, 900);
        params.setPictureFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);
        params.setJpegQuality(85);
        mCamera.setParameters(params);

        // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
        mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);

        // Calculating the width of the preview so it is proportional.
        float widthFloat = (float) (deviceHeight) * 4 / 3;
        int width = Math.round(widthFloat);

        // Resizing the LinearLayout so we can make a proportional preview. This
        // approach is not 100% perfect because on devices with a really small
        // screen the the image will still be distorted - there is place for
        // improvment.
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, deviceHeight);
        preview.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        // Adding the camera preview after the FrameLayout and before the button
        // as a separated element.
        preview.addView(mPreview, 0);
    }
```

You may see `complete` **CameraActivity** class code [here](https://github.com/davidgatti/dgCam/blob/staging/src/pl/gatti/dgcam/DgCamActivity.java)

And Here is my `CameraPreview` class:

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        mHolder.setFixedSize(100, 100);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the
        // preview.
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("DG_DEBUG", "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // make any resize, rotate or reformatting changes here

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90); // Portrait only
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("DG_DEBUG", "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
    }

}
```

Comment: which is line number `124` ?

Comment: please define line no 124

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK the line number 124 is mCamera.setParameters(params);

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Issue is caused by:

```
params.setPictureSize(1200, 900);
```

because required size is not suppoerted by Camera.

Use `getSupportedPictureSizes` to get all available preview sizes.

To check which is maximum picture size available from camera:

```
List<Size> allSizes = param.getSupportedPictureSizes();
Camera.Size size = allSizes.get(0); // get top size
for (int i = 0; i < allSizes.size(); i++) {
     if (allSizes.get(i).width > size.width)
       size = allSizes.get(i);
 }
//set max Picture Size
 params.setPictureSize(size.width, size.height);
```

Comment: ok thank you so much, but what If I would like to save my images in 1200 X 900 size into sdcard

Comment: @Sonali: you can do it by changing in hight-width of Bitmap which is returned from Camera for image before save on sd-card. but probably this will effect on image quality . try it let me know

Comment: It was not working on my Huawei P10 for the first time, but then I realized that I was setting "parameters.setFocusMode( Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO );" on my front camera where my front camera does not have focus.

Answer (score 1):

Any Camera App is restricted by the Camera HAL supported for that device. So in Camera HAL we define that we will provide a list of supported size, these sizes could be preview size, picture size or video size. 
so I think you are facing this issue, because 1200*900 is not supported by camera HAL or lower level code.

Comment: exactly, I agree with you... and thanks for info but How Can I take control on it ?

Comment: Actually you can't .. what you can do is, fetch the supported size and write your code accordingly.